# Bootstrap Nav being weird

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bare bones code I have saved so I can start from there when I create a bootstrap site. Today I was playing with the responsive code for one I am working on and the nav bar is mysteriously not giving me a transparent background. I tested giving it a color background and it works, but there is some kind of secondary background behind it remaining at a light gray. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here is a link to the site in progress. Sorry it's super messy right now.
http://dismantledesign.com/phantasm

Here is the CSS that should be changing the navbar to transparent. I can't seem to find the culprit of keeping the navbar gray.

```
@media(min-width:768px){
  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse{ background: none; border: none; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav{ float: right; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li{ margin-left: 20px; color: #fff; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{ color: #fff; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{ color: #fff; }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus{ color: #fff; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code. If you check .navbar-default css there is already background color is applied that is `#f8f8f8` change it to the transparent or none.

```
.navbar-default {
   background-color: transparent ; 
}
```

or you can also add these It's working fine

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default {
   background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `!important`.

Comment: I don't like using important. However I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: it's working fine in inspect tool. Did you tried in inspect tool?

Comment: Specifying just navbar-default alone worked. I never had to do this before. It worked with my posted code just fine. So it is solved now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've made your component transparent, see

You're unable to display your component transparently, because the class you're using has **background-color** property set to *#f8f8f8* (**.navbar-default**).

I suggest you to override the background property, for example **background-color: #000 !important;** by applying CSS inline or give the component some class and then make the background-color of your choice and then you're free to set **opacity:0.8** or anything you want.

Hope you get it, let me know if you're stuck.

Comment: As a note, using !important is not count as good practice. If you want to follow best practices you either remove the class that setting the background-color or you remove the property in the CSS itself.

Comment: I was able to get it by just styling .navbar-default. I do not use !important. Thank you for your response.